Clang Tidy fails with error: no such file or directory: '/ARG'; did you mean '/ARG'?
I am currently in the process of changing my project from just msvc to clang-cl. The source code is almost exclusively c++17, apart from some thirdparty libs i am using.
The app complies and runs fine with clang-cl, but i am having problems with getting clang-tidy to work. One of the later goals will be to use in clang-tidy in a gitlab workflow, but currently i am trying to get it to work locally, so i am running commands from console.
I have read the and followed the instructions in the LLVM documentation, and i also checked that yes, the compile command are indeed exported into compile_commands.json. I also checked the CMakeCache and it also seems to be in order.
Tools used:

Visual Studio 2019 16.11.35
CMake version 3.28.3
Ninja version 1.9.0
Clang-cl (Clang bundled with VS 2019, clang version 12.0.0, Target: i686-pc-windows-msvc)
Clang-tidy (LLVM bundled with VS 2019, LLVM version 12.0.0, Optimized build, Default target: i686-pc-windows-msvc)

Target platform is Windows 11.
Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example:
C:/Projects/MRE/CMakePresets.json
{
  "version": 8,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "debug",
      "displayName": "Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "x86",
        "strategy": "external"
      },
      "cmakeExecutable": "C:\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM": "C:\\ninja\\ninja.exe",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
        "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "clang-cl",
        "CMAKE_C_FLAGS": "-m32",
        "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "clang-cl",
        "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "-m32",
        "CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS": "/errorlimit:0 /debug:full",
        "CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS": "ON"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "release",
      "displayName": "Release",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "x86",
        "strategy": "external"
      },
      "cmakeExecutable": "C:\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM": "C:\\ninja\\ninja.exe",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
        "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "clang-cl",
        "CMAKE_C_FLAGS": "-m32",
        "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "clang-cl",
        "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "-m32",
        "CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS": "/errorlimit:0 /debug:full",
        "CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS": "ON"
      }
    }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    {
      "name": "debug",
      "configurePreset": "debug"
    },
    {
      "name": "release",
      "configurePreset": "release"
    }
  ]
}

C:/Projects/MRE/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
set(TARGET_NAME MRE_Main)

project(MRE VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES C CXX)
set(SOURCES
    "Source/main.cpp"
)

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SOURCES})

C:/Projects/MRE/Source/main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}

Building the project:

Open Visual Studio 2019, and select 'Open a local folder'. Select C:/Projects/MRE folder, or wherever your copy is.
Rewrite the path to CMake and Ninja in CMakePresets.json, to point to your installations.
In VS, up at the toolbar press Project -> Configure MRE
Build debug version of MRE_Main.exe

Alternatively you can build from console:

Rewrite the path to CMake and Ninja in CMakePresets.json, to point to your installations.
Open 'Developer Command Prompt for VS2019', and enter the following commands
cd C:\Projects\MRE
set PATH=C:\CMake\bin\;C:\ninja\;%PATH% (Rewrite paths to point to your installations)
cmake --preset debug
cmake --preset --build debug

Steps to reproduce:

Open 'Developer Command Prompt for VS2019', and enter the following commands! If you built from console, and have the same console still open, then you can skip to step 4.
cd C:\Projects\MRE
set PATH=C:\CMake\bin\;C:\ninja\;%PATH% (Again, rewrite paths to point to your installations)
clang-tidy -p=./build/debug/ Source/main.cpp

For me output is:
C:\Projects\MRE>clang-tidy -p=./build/debug/ Source/main.cpp
2 errors generated.
Error while processing C:\Projects\MRE\Source\main.cpp.
error: no such file or directory: '-fsyntax-only'; did you mean '-fsyntax-only'? [clang-diagnostic-error]
error: no such file or directory: '-resource-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\Llvm\lib\clang\12.0.0'; did you mean '-resource-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\Llvm\lib\clang\12.0.0'? [clang-diagnostic-error]
Found compiler error(s).

I checked on 2 different computers with the exact same tools installed, and i get the same results.
To me it seems the problem is an extra ';' at the end of complier arguments, but i can not find anyone with the same problem, and have no clue how to fix it.
I also checked for .clang-tidy files, and found none on the path. As a drastic measure, I deleted every single .clang-tidy file, no matter where it was. Still the same result. Not sure where the -fsyntax-only flag comes from.
Edit:
Here is the requested clang-tidy --dump-config.
---
Checks:          'clang-diagnostic-*,clang-analyzer-*'
WarningsAsErrors: ''
HeaderFilterRegex: ''
AnalyzeTemporaryDtors: false
FormatStyle:     none
User:            user
CheckOptions:
  - key:             llvm-else-after-return.WarnOnConditionVariables
    value:           '0'
  - key:             modernize-loop-convert.MinConfidence
    value:           reasonable
  - key:             modernize-replace-auto-ptr.IncludeStyle
    value:           llvm
  - key:             cert-str34-c.DiagnoseSignedUnsignedCharComparisons
    value:           '0'
  - key:             google-readability-namespace-comments.ShortNamespaceLines
    value:           '10'
  - key:             cert-oop54-cpp.WarnOnlyIfThisHasSuspiciousField
    value:           '0'
  - key:             cppcoreguidelines-non-private-member-variables-in-classes.IgnoreClassesWithAllMemberVariablesBeingPublic
    value:           '1'
  - key:             cert-dcl16-c.NewSuffixes
    value:           'L;LL;LU;LLU'
  - key:             google-readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines
    value:           '1'
  - key:             modernize-pass-by-value.IncludeStyle
    value:           llvm
  - key:             google-readability-namespace-comments.SpacesBeforeComments
    value:           '2'
  - key:             modernize-loop-convert.MaxCopySize
    value:           '16'
  - key:             cppcoreguidelines-explicit-virtual-functions.IgnoreDestructors
    value:           '1'
  - key:             modernize-use-nullptr.NullMacros
    value:           'NULL'
  - key:             llvm-qualified-auto.AddConstToQualified
    value:           '0'
  - key:             modernize-loop-convert.NamingStyle
    value:           CamelCase
  - key:             llvm-else-after-return.WarnOnUnfixable
    value:           '0'
  - key:             google-readability-function-size.StatementThreshold
    value:           '800'
...



I tried to reproduce the issue without the CMakePresets.json.  Without CMakePresets I cannot reproduce the problem. The thing is i would heavily prefer using presets, so this is not a real solution.

What I meant by "everything else worked fine" is that clang-tidy ran for me without any complaints.  I have different versions of the various tools; I have VS 2022 instead of 2019, and my versions of the other tools are also different.  But the main issue remains: where are -fsyntax-only and -resource-dir coming from?  I'm stumped, unfortunately.  (BTW, the semicolon is not the problem, that is just a fixed part of the error message.)

I will try VS 2022, maybe that will solve my problem. What stumps me is i already tried 3 different machines, 2 in work 1 at home, and i get the same result.
Can you provide your versions? I might consider switching versions just to get this to work.

Can confirm, VS 2022 works with MRE. Now the original project remains to be tested, and i expect there will be some problems when switching versions, so that might take.
Btw VS2022 came with LLVM 17.0.3 so that is 5 major version of difference, so it makes sense that it is no longer a problem.

Ah, knowing VS 2022 and LLVM-17 worked for you was enough to track the issue down almost to its source.  Strange bug!

The error is due to a bug in LLVM-12 and earlier relating to how it
handles -- in the compile_commands.json command line.  It was fixed
in LLVM-13 or LLVM-14.  It does not involve Visual Studio.  It involves
cmake only because cmake creates compile_commands.json with the
-- switch that provokes the bug.  The bug manifests on both Windows
and Linux.
Reproducer
Create an empty source file, and a compile_commands.json that has a
command line with -- before the file name.  Then run clang-tidy on
that file.
Example showing the bug when using LLVM-11:
$ cat test.cpp

$ cat compile_commands.json
[
{
  "directory": "/home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/clang-tidy-syntax-only-bug",
  "command": "clang.exe -c -- test.cpp",
  "file": "/home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/clang-tidy-syntax-only-bug/test.cpp"
}
]

$ ~/opt/clang+llvm-11.0.1-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04/bin/clang-tidy test.cpp
2 errors generated.
Error while processing /home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/clang-tidy-syntax-only-bug/test.cpp.
error: no such file or directory: '-fsyntax-only'; did you mean '-fsyntax-only'? [clang-diagnostic-error]
error: no such file or directory: '-resource-dir=/home/scott/opt/clang+llvm-11.0.1-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04/lib/clang/11.0.1'; did you mean '-resource-dir=/home/scott/opt/clang+llvm-11.0.1-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04/lib/clang/11.0.1'? [clang-diagnostic-error]
Found compiler error(s).
Exit 1

Example showing that it works with LLVM-14, executed right after the
previous command:
$ ~/opt/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin/clang-tidy test.cpp
(No output, exit code 0.)

Solution
Either upgrade to LLVM-14 or later, or remove the -- in the command
line in compile_commands.json (and arrange to keep removing it despite
cmake putting it there).
As it happens, VS 2019 ships with LLVM-12, while VS 2022 ships with
LLVM-17, so upgrading to VS 2022 also solves the problem when using
its clang-tidy.
Existing bug report
This bug was filed against LLVM github as
Issue 49639: Clang-Tidy reports wrong command line argument even though it is not specified at all
back in May 2021.
However, the cause couldn't be determined and it was eventually closed
as invalid.
Where does -fsyntax-only come from?
It comes from clang-tidy itself, in
Tooling.cpp:
static std::vector<std::string>
getSyntaxOnlyToolArgs(const Twine &ToolName,
                      const std::vector<std::string> &ExtraArgs,
                      StringRef FileName) {
  std::vector<std::string> Args;
  Args.push_back(ToolName.str());
  Args.push_back("-fsyntax-only");
  Args.insert(Args.end(), ExtraArgs.begin(), ExtraArgs.end());
  Args.push_back(FileName.str());
  return Args;
}

The -resource-dir argument also comes from the same file:
static void injectResourceDir(CommandLineArguments &Args, const char *Argv0,
                              void *MainAddr) {
  // Allow users to override the resource dir.
  for (StringRef Arg : Args)
    if (Arg.startswith("-resource-dir"))
      return;

  // If there's no override in place add our resource dir.
  Args.push_back("-resource-dir=" +
                 CompilerInvocation::GetResourcesPath(Argv0, MainAddr));
}

These options were evidently being placed after the -- that was
found in compile_commands.json, and therefore interpreted as input
file names by the rest of the driver infrastructure.  That causes the
err_drv_no_such_file_with_suggestion
error message to be printed:
def err_drv_no_such_file_with_suggestion : Error<
  "no such file or directory: '%0'; did you mean '%1'?">;

Which change fixed it?
I don't know.  I couldn't find any other issues that seemed related
(PR 66553 is in the
vicinity but is too recent), and didn't dig deeper than what's reported
above to find the bug itself.
